# “Document Map” UI control for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Using wpf/c#, I need to create a “document map tree” with collapable tree nodes that Scans a text file and looks for header levels as defined by markdown:

```
/# header level 1
/## header level 2
/### header level 3
Etc…
```

i was thinking about using a TreeView UI control to do this … however, the problem I have with it is that markdown can skip levels and go directly from level 1 header down to level 4 header. Example:

```
/# animals
/#### little ones
/#### big ones
/### amibas
/### squirrels  
/#### flying ones
/# rocks
/## shiny rocks
```

Somehow I need to get a treeview that can jump to any depth, instead of advancing by only one level per node…
Any ideas?

One idea I had was to store the headers in a listbox with indents and then hide and unhide items in the list view depending on if they are expanded or not expanded…

Answer (score 1):

You need to create own model and populate it based on file content

```
//NodeModel.cs
public class NodeModel {
    public NodeModel ParentNode {get;set;}
    
    public IsRootNode {get} => ParentNode==null;  

    public List<NodeModel> ChildNodes {get;} = new List<NodeModel>();

    public string Name { get;set;}

}

//DataProvider.cs
public IEnumerable<NodeModel> GetHeadersFromFile (string fileName)
{
    var nodes = List<NodeModel>()

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
         while(var line = sr.ReadLine()) {
            if (!line.StartWith("/#") continue;

            var level = line.IndexOf(" ")-"/#".Length; // can be 0,1,2

            if (nodes.Lenght + 1 < level) {
                // adjust level
                level = Lenght + 1;
                
                // .. or probably need to create missing subnodes
                //while (nodes.Lenght + 1 < level)
                //{
                //   var skippedNode = new NodeModel()
                //   {
                //      ParentNode = nodes.LastOrDefault(),
                //      Name = $"Node on level {level}"
                //   }
                //   nodes.Add(skippedNode);
                //   skippedNode.Parent.ChildNodes.Add(skippedNode);
                //}
             
                // or just throw exception because file not valid
                // throw new Exception($"Header for the level {nodeHierarchy.Lenght + 1} was not found");
            }

            // case when after /##### next is /## or /#
            // remove parent nodes
            while (nodes.Length != 0 && (nodes.Lenght + 1) > level) {
               nodes.Remove(nodes.Last());
            }

            // get parentNodel
            var parentNode = nodes.LastOrDefault();

            var node = new NodeModel(){
                ParentNode = parentNode,
                Name = line.Substring(level + 2); // return rest of line
            }; 

            if (parentNode!=null) {
               parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(node);
            }

            yield return node;                      
         };
    }
}
```

Then you can use own data provider, get collection of nodes
and assign it as ItemsSource to your treeView.

```
// MyWindow.xaml
<TreeView x:Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:NodeModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>

// MyWindowViewModel.cs
public class MyWindowViewModel{
   public ObservableCollection<NodeModel> Nodes {get;} => new ObservableCollection<NodeModel>();
}

// MyWindow.xaml.cs
public class MyWindow : Window{

   // ctor
   public MyWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponents();
       Loaded += OnLoaded;

       this.DataSource = new MyWindowViewModel();
   }
    
   // just for demonstation for get headers.
   public void Loaded(sender objet, EventArgs args)
   {
      if (this.DataSource is MyWindowViewModelvm)
      {

      var provider = new DataProvider(); // use IoC if possible
      var rootNodes=  provider.GetHeadersFromFile('someFile').Where(n=>n.IsRootNode).ToList();

      // populate only root items - treeView will load the subitems via property ChildItems which was specified in HierarchicalDataTemplate
      vm.Nodes.Clear();
      vm.Nodes.AddRange(rootNodes);

      }
   }
}
```

This is example for how to use TreeView with hierachical data.